# Bring application into foreground when called again

Tags: python, linux, pyqt5, gnome

I am currently contributing to a GUI application based on Python and PyQt5 supporting Linux (and macOS). This application relies heavily on the system tray. The tray icon is for example used to bring the main window to the foreground again.

To make this application usable under DEs without a system tray (e.g. GNOME) it would be necessary to have another way to bring the window back when the application is running, but the window is closed.

I think the best solution would be to bring the window to the foreground when the application is called again (instead of opening another instance, the current instance opens the window). I already found out that D-Bus exists and that it allows communication between applications, also this [Qt example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdbus-chat-example.html)! seems adaptable to my problem. However, I am still overwhelmed with this task and wonder if there might even exist a better solution (which might in the ideal case also work on macOS)

Comment: The solution depends on each OS, so I recommend you create a post for each OS so you can get several answers that join them have your general solution in less time since the developers of Qt / PyQt not necessarily work with all OS.

Comment: Thank you!
Would you recommend to delete this post and create two new ones with similar content but different tags?

Comment: I would recommend editing this current question and only indicate an OS, since in SO there is a minimum period to create a new question

Comment: Okay, I will do that!

Comment: There are a number of options that are cross-platform, or close enough.  Using named pipes on Windows and unix sockets on linux/unix, for example, are almost the same solution, and can do this. Shared memory is similar across platforms as well. TCP port listening is basically identical across the platforms. DBus on Windows should work, but may or may not be more painful to set up (since it's not a default) than it's worth, not sure.

Comment: I dunno. I've had to maintain "system tray" aware apps for a few apps, and in those cases we had core code that was wrapped by platform specific runtime code to provide the expected functionality that wouldn't break the next time the platform was updated. If you don't want to anger 2/3 of your users, anyway. And then there are the installer/deployment issues related to this...